# Seek asp.net library to integrate Google services

Tags: asp.net, gdata-api

Sometime earlier this week i saw a reference to a commercial library (think was priced at 299) that wrapped up all the various GoogleDocs family of services - have lost the link. I've searched codeplex and VS's Library Manager without joy.

I'm aware of Google's sdk but would prefer working with a higher abstraction - though a verbose kickstarter project that integrates gData to an asp.net datatier would be nice.

thx

Comment: Did you check your browser history? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this it? http://rssbus.com/ado/google/